# Why doesn't re-render Vue the component after changing the Pinia state (deleteing an object in Array)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a deleteHandler function, which changes the users array in pinia. However, in the devtools in vue, the state is changed, but the component didn't re-render, but if I instead deleting the object from the array, just change some values, then vue recognize it and re-render the component, only by deleting the object from the array doesn't work.

```
const deleteHandler = (user) => {
  //doesn't renders
    useUser.users = useUser.users.filter(usr => usr.id !== user.id) 
  //it works, the component is re-rendered
  useUser.users.forEach(usr => {
    usr.points += 1
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it some kind of reference issue.
Please try this one

```
useUser.users = [...useUser.users.filter(usr => usr.id !== user.id)];
```

insted of

```
useUser.users = useUser.users.filter(usr => usr.id !== user.id)
```

Comment: I found a solution, the problem was that the "topTenUser" which is from made from the users, I call it like {topTenUsers} = useUserStore(), instead of useUser = useUserStore(), and then put the useUser.topTenUser in a component as a prop. Didn't know that if I destructure the state, it will lose the reactivity. Anyway, thanks for help!

Comment: You can use `storeToRefs` and still destructure the Pinia state and getters without losing reactivity. If you are trying to destructure the action, then it will work, and you don't need to use `storeToRefs` in that case because functions are hoisted in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are getting data from the store using `storeToRefs()` method of Pinia. It will only work if you are only using state from the store but not calling any action.

```js
import { useCounterStore } from '@/stores/counter'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const store = useCounterStore()
// `name` and `doubleCount` are reactive refs
// This will also extract refs for properties added by plugins
// but skip any action or non reactive (non ref/reactive) property
const { name, doubleCount } = storeToRefs(store)
// the increment action can just be destructured
const { increment } = store
```